# Service cannot be started Access Denied

Tags: wcf

> Service cannot be started. System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException:
>   The service endpoint failed to listen on the URI
>   'net.tcp://ssis01:9176/SSISService_v2_0/' because access was denied. 
>   Verify that the current user is granted access in the appropriate
>   allowAccounts section of SMSvcHost.exe.config. --->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.SharedMemory.Read(String name, String&
>   content)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedConnectionListener.SharedListenerProxy.ReadEndpoint(String
>   sharedMemoryName, String& listenerEndpoint)    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedConnectionListener.SharedListenerProxy.ReadEndpoint(String
>   sharedMemoryName, String& listenerEndpoint)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedConnectionListener.SharedListenerProxy.HandleServiceStart(Boolean
>   isReconnecting)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedConnectionListener.SharedListenerProxy.Open(Boolean
>   isReconnecting)    at System.Ser.

**What i have tried** 
I am not a administrator maybe that is the issue , for that

1) added my user SID in SMSvcHost.exe.config in allowAccounts section .. Then restarted the service first NETSharing and then the SSISService

2) when starting ssis Service it throws an error "Service on local computer started and stopped. Some Services stops automatically if they are not in use by others services and programs. Above ERROR msg are from the Logs

Here is the config file for SMSvcHost.exe.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- The configuration file for SMSvcHost.exe -->
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <gcConcurrent enabled="false" />
    </runtime>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <!-- SMSvcHost ETW traces are redirected by default to an etwProviderId different from WCF's default. 
             To trace to the default provider, remove the etwProviderId attribute below. -->
        <diagnostics performanceCounters="Off" etwProviderId="{f18839f5-27ff-4e66-bd2d-639b768cf18b}"/>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.serviceModel.activation>
        <net.tcp listenBacklog="10" maxPendingConnections="100" maxPendingAccepts="2" receiveTimeout="00:00:10" teredoEnabled="false">
        <allowAccounts>
            <add securityIdentifier="S-1-5-21-873128402-3342024598-2051005476-53521"/>
        </allowAccounts>
        </net.tcp>          
    </system.serviceModel.activation>       
</configuration>
```

Comment: i have also tried to add the service in CMD command prompt                Netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:9176/SSISService_V2_0 user =domain\user

Comment: WCF services will only run under admin rights. Either run the service host from an admin cmd prompt, or run VS as a administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me a while to fix this issue

Step1. In the Run command window **regedit.exe**

Step 2 : go to the Location ( path is at the bottom of screenshot) ,  to get the SID for the Adminstrator.
[image]

Step3: Copy the SID for the Admin , here you will see the SID for all the user that is logged in. But you only want it for ADMIN, how to know it is admin ? 
     Right Click on service and go to Properties and click Log on Tab. 
     If you see the screen shot 1 you will see the **ProfileImagePath** has the same name **DataSVC**.

[image]

Step 3: Main part Config changes 
add this line of code with the ADMIN SID in SMSvcHost.exe.config .

```
<system.serviceModel.activation>
        <net.tcp listenBacklog="10" maxPendingConnections="100" maxPendingAccepts="2" receiveTimeout="00:00:10" teredoEnabled="false">
        <allowAccounts>
            <add securityIdentifier="**ADMIN SID ID HERE** "/>
        </allowAccounts>
        </net.tcp>          
    </system.serviceModel.activation>
```

Step 5 : Restart NETTCP sharing first and then the other service. should fix the issue for this ERROR. thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in your question you are getting this error because your user doesn't have sufficient privilege, running visual studio as administrator is one way to fix this issue.